# How to return the xlsx file to local via google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to download xlsx file from my Google Sheet via google script.
But the file I downloaded cannot be opened correctly.

```
function doGet(e)
{
//Get My Spreadsheet 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

//Create URL to Export as xlsx
var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

//Get the file 
var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
//Get the blob
var blob = file.getBlob();

// sets the file extension 
blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");

return ContentService.createTextOutput(file.getContentText()).downloadAsFile("Test.xlsx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, `downloadAsFile(filename)` can be used for the text file. I thought that this is the reason of your issue.

In your situation, it is required to use a workaround. This workaround uses an HTML service. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + spreadsheetId + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
  var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var blob = file.getBlob();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplate('<body></body><script>const a=document.createElement("a");document.body.appendChild(a),a.download="<?= filename ?>",a.href="<?= data ?>",a.click();</script>');
  html.data = "data:application/pdf;base64," + Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
  html.filename = ss.getName() + ".xlsx";
  return html.evaluate();
}
```

- When this web apps is accessed after this script was reflected in the Web Apps, the spreadsheet of `spreadsheetId` is converted to XLSX data and it is automatically downloaded.

#### Note:

- In your script, it seems that Web Apps is used. **In this case, when you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [downloadAsFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output#downloadAsFile(String))
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#eventobject)